# HTML & CSS: Hiding the cookie bar after clicking on "I accept"

Tags: html, css, cookies

I am working on a web site, and I wanted to know how is it possible to hide the cookie notice after clicking on "I accept" or whatever. I don't want to use webkits, I want pure HTML (and CSS if needed), or even PHP.

```css
#cookie-bar.fixed {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 5;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            
        }

        #cookie-bar {
            line-height: 24px;
            color: #eeeeee;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 3px 0;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            background-color: #444;
            
            
        }

        .cb-enable {
            border-radius: 10%;
            margin-left: 100px;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;   
            border-radius: 10%;
            font-family: serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: .3s background-color;
            
            
            
         }
        
        .cb-enable:hover {
            background-color: darkcyan;
        }
        
        .cb-policy {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        .cb-policy:hover {
            color: darkcyan;
        }
```

```html
   <div id="cookie-bar" class="fixed">
     <p>We use cookies to enhance your experience in our web site. By visiting it, you agree our <a href="/privacy-policy/#cookies" class="cb-policy">Cookies Policy</a>
       <a href="#" class="cb-enable">I Understand</a>
       </p>
    
  </div>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the piece of code that i use for all my projects. It's pretty easy to understand. All you have to do is to create a cookie with javascript once the user click on "ok" and then you check if the cookie is set. If so, the disclaimer won't show.

```
<?if (!isset($_COOKIE["disclaimer"])){?>
    <div id="cookie_disclaimer">
        <div>
            <div class="titolo">COOKIE POLICY</div>

            blablabla cookie disclaimer blablabla

            <span id="cookie_stop">Ok</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?}?>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $('#cookie_stop').click(function(){
        $('#cookie_disclaimer').slideUp();

        var nDays = 999;
        var cookieName = "disclaimer";
        var cookieValue = "true";

        var today = new Date();
        var expire = new Date();
        expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
        document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+";expires="+expire.toGMTString()+";path=/";
     });

});
</script>
```

If you don't want to use javascript/jquery you can just do the same but with a form, but the user will se the page reloading and to me it's not so good to see

Comment: Don't forget to set cookies HttpOnly and Secure flags.

Answer (score 3):

Using local storage to store a variable saying if cookie was accepted or not.
This is only an example. If you want to separate by sessions you just need to use localstorage to check your sessions.

JS

```
window.onload = function(){
    try {
        if(localStorage.getItem("cookie-enable")!="1"){
            document.getElementById("cookie-bar").style.display="block";
        }
        document.getElementById("save-cookie-example").addEventListener( "click", function() {
            localStorage.setItem("cookie-enable", "1");
            document.getElementById("cookie-bar").style.display="none";
        } );
    } catch( e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#cookie-bar.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;

}

#cookie-bar {
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #444;
    display:none;
}

.cb-enable {
    border-radius: 10%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;   
    border-radius: 10%;
    font-family: serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s background-color;



 }

.cb-enable:hover {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.cb-policy {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.cb-policy:hover {
    color: darkcyan;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="cookie-bar" class="fixed">
    <p>We use cookies to enhance your experience in our web site. By visiting it, you agree our <a href="/privacy-policy/#cookies" class="cb-policy">Cookies Policy</a>
        <a href="#" id="save-cookie-example"class="cb-enable">I Understand</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about : `onclick="parentNode.remove()"`

EDIT:

This seems to work like a charm for me?

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'"
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyzevdbL/)

This would only work each time u click if I'm correct.

I would suggest using: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/